# Issue with sum when drawing new card - BlackJack

Tags: java, blackjack

I'm having problem with my code for a simple game similar to BlackJack in Swing. The user can draw two cards and the program can calculate the two cards correctly, but when the user wants to press the button (I use a JButton) to get a new card it doesn't go as planed.

Note: it's a very simple version. No cards above 10.

For example: first cards = 2 + 5 = 7 
The user presses "New Card" to get a new one.
The new card is 4 --> i.e. 7 + 4 = 11 ==== not even close to being busted, yet the program sometimes tells the user it's busted.

Where in my code is the error? Where can I improve it and fix it?

```js
 /*
  *Write a program that draws a card of value 1 to 10. 
  *Determine the sum of the cards so far. 
  *Keep drawing cards while the sum is less than 16. Output the total sum. 
  *If the sum is greater than 21 output “Bust”. 
  */
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*; 
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;//random number generator
import java.util.ArrayList;//Array lists

class CardGame extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
 
 JLabel välkommenMessage = new JLabel ("Welcome to BlackJack   ");
 JTextArea spelRegler = new JTextArea("Klicka på 'Draw Card' för att få dina två första kort.\nOm kortsumman är under 16, fortsätt dra kort.\nKommer du över 21 förlorar du. ");
 
 JButton cardButton = new JButton ("Draw Card");
 JButton newCard = new JButton ("New Card");
    JLabel kortText = new JLabel("");
 static JLabel blackJackSumma = new JLabel ("");
 static JLabel displayNewCard = new JLabel("");
 JLabel stödlinjenText = new JLabel ("18+. Stödlinjen: 020-819 100");
 
 static Random randomCard = new Random(); 
 
 
 public CardGame (){
  super("Card Game");
  setSize (270,250);
  setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  setVisible (true);
  Container contentArea = getContentPane();
  contentArea.setBackground(Color.white);
  FlowLayout flowManager = new FlowLayout();
  contentArea.setLayout(flowManager);
  spelRegler.setEditable(false);
  
  
  cardButton.addActionListener(this);
  newCard.addActionListener(this);
  
  contentArea.add(välkommenMessage);
  contentArea.add(spelRegler);
  contentArea.add(stödlinjenText);
  contentArea.add(cardButton);
  contentArea.add(kortText);
  
  contentArea.add(displayNewCard);
  contentArea.add(blackJackSumma);
        contentArea.add(newCard);
  setContentPane(contentArea);
  
 } 
 
 public static int cardDraw () {
   int card = randomCard.nextInt(10) + 1;
   return card;
 }

     public static ArrayList<Integer> drawTwoCards(){
        ArrayList<Integer> cards = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
     {
         cards.add(cardDraw());
     }
        return cards;
   }
     

   public static int cardsSumma(ArrayList<Integer> cards){
    int total = 0;
    for(int card :cards){ 
       total = total + card;
     }
    return total;
   }
    
    public static void spelaKort(ArrayList<Integer> cards){
     
     int newCard = cardDraw(); //call for method
     cards.add(newCard); 
     displayNewCard.setText("Your card: " + newCard);
     blackJackSumma.setText("Total: "+ cardsSumma(cards));
 
 if (cardsSumma(cards)== 21){
  blackJackSumma.setText("You win");
  return; 
  }
 else if (cardsSumma(cards)> 21){
  blackJackSumma.setText("BUSTED!");
  return;
 }
 else{                             
  blackJackSumma.setText("Total: " + cardsSumma(cards));
  System.out.print(cardsSumma(cards));
  spelaKort(cards);
  }
    }
 
    
 public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event){ 

     if (event.getSource()== cardButton){
      ArrayList<Integer> cards = drawTwoCards();
   kortText.setText("Card: " + cards.get(0) +" and " + cards.get(1)+ "   Total: " + cardsSumma(cards));
   if (cardsSumma(cards)< 21){
               spelRegler.setText("Press 'New Card' to continue");
              }
   
    }
  if (event.getSource()==newCard){
   ArrayList<Integer> cards = drawTwoCards();
   spelaKort(cards); 
  }
  }
     
 }


public class Worksheet37a {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  
  CardGame Win = new CardGame();
  
 }

}
```

Comment: I admit I haven't totally looked over your code, but you can't keep a running total because of aces which can count as one or eleven, right?

Comment: @MichaelKrause in this very simple version i don't use cards over 10 :)

Comment: Well - it looks like when newCard is clicked that you draw two cards and then pass that into your play cards method which draws yet another card for a total of 3.  Is this what you intended?

Comment: @MichaelKrause I intend to draw two cards with the first button, but only add one card at a time with the second button.